# How to access variable declared inside promise in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, protractor, nodes

I have a use case where i should access promise result variable should be scoped to global variable or outside scope

```
var mobileNumber = database.generateMobileNumber().then(function(number) {
return number;//number should be access outside this function scope
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable and assign value in the promise that your function returns and wait until the promise is resolved. Here's how -

```
var mobileNumber = '';
browser.wait(function(){
    return database.generateMobileNumber().then(function(number) {
        mobileNumber = number;
        return !!number;
    );
}).then(function(){
    //mobileNumber should be accessible here
});
```

Note: Because you don't know when the promise returns, using `wait()` function should help until value is returned. Also if you are using the value after some operations, then there is no need of chaining `wait()` function with `.then()`.

Hope it helps.